# Is this the right approach to soldering really small wires?

Tags: soldering

This is my first time trying to solder some really small wires.  I'm going to try to solder this **first end**:

[image]

With this **second end**:

[image]

I removed the black wrap around the second end to fully expose the copper wires:

[image]
[image]

Because I've never done this before, I want to know if my following approach will be correct?

1. I am going to intertwine the inner copper strands of the red wire of the first end with the inner copper strands of the red wire of the second end.  Then solder.  Then apply a plastic insulator around the soldered area.
2. I am going to intertwine the outer copper strands of the red wire of the first end with the inner copper strands of the black wire of second end. Then solder.  Then apply a plastic insulator around the soldered area.
3. I am going to intertwine the inner copper strands of the white wire of the first end with the inner strands of the white wire of the second end.  Then solder.  Then apply a plastic insulator around the soldered area.
4. I will leave the outer copper strands of the white wire of the first end unconnected.

These wires seem so small to me that I feel like I'm going to mess something up.  But to everyone else, is this a very common soldering job?  I welcome insight on how best to solder these.

**EDIT**

These wires were previously connected.  But there was a problematic connection around the strain relief of the connection, so someone suggested that I remove the problematic area and re-build the connection.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "intertwine", but have a look at this, you might find it helpful: https://1abxf1rh6g01lhm2riyrt55k-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/How-to-Splice-and-Solder-to-NASA-Standards_e-2-copy.jpg

Comment: Thanks yes that image was what I meant by intertwine

Comment: Whatever else you do, remember to put the heatshrink over the wires *before* soldering them, if that is what you meant by "plastic insulator".

Comment: These appear to be [coaxial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable) cables. They have a center conductor and an outer shield, separated by white or red insulation. Confusingly, the outer shield is separated and ran through black heat-shrink tubing *on opposing ends* of the cables, making it seem like "a black wire" is it's own wire but it is not. *A co-ax always has a center conductor and an outer shield*.

Comment: @rdtsc do I need to solder the shields together?

Comment: In the last photo, both coax with the white insulator have nothing connected to their shields. I would leave them this way (shields not connected to anything.) If you make connections where there were none before, it could spell trouble.